# Pass parameters to Iframe flex

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, iframe, actionscript

I am new to flex. I have used iframe to embed html page into my flex application. Here is the following code to embed the html file :

```
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml"
xmlns:flexiframe="http://code.google.com/p/flexiframe/">
<flexiframe:IFrame id="googleIFrame"
label="Google"
source="http://heatmap.html"
width="80%"
height="80%"/><mx:Application>
```

The challenge what I'm facing is that I want to pass parameter to html page        (HeatMap.html) when loaded from iframe.

How to pass the parameters? Do I need to write separate function?

Comment: What kind of parameter do you want to pass.? If it's `GET` parameters, then you can do it like, modify the link to `http://heatmap.html?param1=value&param2=value` format.

Comment: I want to pass the parameters like ids to html page. Should i modify the code as <flexiframe:IFrame id="googleIFrame"
label="Google"
source="http://heatmap.html?param1=value&param2=value"
width="80%"
height="80%"/>

Comment: Then how do i access those parameters in html page?

Comment: I don't know whether this will help you. Just take a look. http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf626ae-7feb.html

Comment: i want to pass parameters from flex to Html. I have embedded html page using IFRame

Answer (score 0):

You can write a function on HTML page and call the function in html page using iFarameid.callIFrameFunction("func_Name",parameters...)